# how to load image in background?

Tags: iphone

I have loaddata from the server and display in the table.But duw to image it will take more time.so i want to load image in the tableview using thread how it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this example from apple:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html