# how to load image in background?

Tags: javascript, image, xmlhttprequest, loading

Problem: I am creating an album.So on every  press of

time "NEXT" button I am loading new Images. What I want to achieve is, I want to switch from old image to new image only once the new images has been downloaded fully from server.

Actually I dont want to show partial images while loading.

Is there any solution?

PS [SIMILAR QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154139/how-to-load-image-in-background) but this is for Iphone. I need for browser?

Comment: Do you have any code at all that you are trying?

Comment: are you looking for image slider?

Comment: @Loktar: sorry to say but I am not able to get any clue for the problem so no code for try :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just make a new image via javascript, and only show the image after the `onload` has fired. This will make sure you don't see any partial rendering of the image.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/VVAjr/1/)**

```
    var curImg = new Image();

    curImg.src = "url to your image";
    curImg.onload = function(){
        // do whatever here, add it to the background, append the image ect.
        imgHolder.appendChild(curImg);   
    }
```

Comment: It worked for me.Thanks. I also 1 more useful links, that's for others http://www.csgnetwork.com/directjsimageobj.html

Comment: Note that at least chrome will display the "web page loading spinner" in its interface until the image is loaded. As a workaround, wrap the snippet above in `window.onload`.

Comment: The image in your example is no longer available.
http://www.realbollywood.com/news/up_images/big-pictures5708.jpg

Comment: @Brandt haha so you down vote it? Apply any other image to it in the fiddle, the code in the answer doesn't require that specific image.

Comment: Sorry was looking for answer and when I went to the demo it did not work so I assumed the code did not work. That is why I down voted. After looking into it found it was a bad image and posted a comment. Won't let me undo the down vote however until 13 more hours. Hope that helps explain.

Answer (score 3):

You can play with 2 img tags. img1 shows the first image, while img2, is hidden, and loads the next image.

At the `onload` event of img2, you can hide img1, and show img2.

And load the next image with img1, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

link rel="prerender" might do the trick.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-html5-prefetching

Comment: Interesting answer, but I don't think this would be useful in this case. The asker needs it for a gallery. If you add more `<link>` tags to the head with `rel="prerender"` through JS, would it work as the asker is intending?