# How to prevent background images loading on image slider

Tags: jquery, css, image, optimization

I'm using unslider to display an image slider on the homepage of my website. I've used background images for the slides in the css which change depending on the media query. I want to prevent the browser loading all of the slider images when it first encounters the css file so that it doesn't slow down loading the rest of the page.

The slider has 4 slides, and I've currently set:

```
.slide2, 
.slide3, 
.slide4 {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in a script at the bottom of the page I've included:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".slide2, .slide3, .slide4").css({"display" : "block"})       
});
```

I've read however that Opera is the only browser that downloads the image when display is set to block, other browsers still load the images immediately.

There is a 10 second delay before it moves to the second slide, so there would be plenty of time to load the remaining slider images after the rest of the page has loaded. I don't want to have to change the background-image attribute with jQuery because there are different images for the sliders depending on the viewport width.

Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: you can pre-load it by using `Image()` constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6294850/2016836

Comment: with 'img' tag is complicated but with backgrounds images there are more possibilities, check this: https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to allocate background-images to the slides after the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide2').css({"background-image" : "url('path/to/your/image2')"});
    $('.slide3').css({"background-image" : "url('path/to/your/image3')"});
    $('.slide4').css({"background-image" : "url('path/to/your/image4')"});
});
```